# Display the actual month as opposed to the number

Tags: sql

I am looking to get the actual month to display using the below statement:

```
SELECT (MONTH(now()) - Month(cases.date_entered)) AS 'Call Month'
```

Comment: Please add tag with RDBMS type.

Comment: I don't know which language this snippet is in so can't be sure but it looks to me like it will be doing date arithmetic on the dates which will return the number of months between.  I suggest you describe what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can get the month name like this:

```
 SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) AS 'Current Month'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this regardless of database is to create a table of month numbers and month names, and join to it.

This won't work in your case though as your query doesn't really return a month number.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL (Wich I suspect is your RDBMS for using the function `NOW()`), you can do this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%M') AS 'Current Month'
```